# Kubernetes nginx-ingress - Record traffic

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, network-traffic

Sometimes, we want to record the traffic on one of our ingresses to be able to replay this traffic at later times, when needed.

I've had a rough look at what's already possible, but I didn't find much.

Is there any kubernetes standard way of doing this? (or should I try to modify the ingresses Nginx container? - yeah, we're using Nginx-ingress)

Comment: Welcome to the community. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by `record the traffic`? What kind of information should be presented?

Comment: Well, the idea is to have the application tested by mirrored traffic from production. Unfortunately, when the app is under development some features are not triggered in production that often. So we thought, that recording live traffic for these scenarios (specific REST calls for example) so we can replay them later. Which means, HTTP-headers and the payload itself to be able to trigger tests on a lower stage when prod traffic isn't there for various reasons. I hope this makes our intention a little more clear.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no standard for this. Ideally in my understanding to log everything on nginx itself to avoid adding more entities in architecture. [One of the possible solutions](https://serverfault.com/a/636819/626733) was described a lot of time ago (may not be relevant nowadays). Since nginx-ingress is basically `nginx` with its configs, it should do the thing.